# Referencing Cells in Power Query (Excel)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a sql query that has the following script. I want to run this query in Excel and replace the values for @Username and @Groupname with cell values in Excel as parameters. How would I go about this? I have the sql code below populating into a table via Power Query. I DO NOT want to filter, I am planning on making this more complicated and these parameters will not actually be part of the results, but will help to FIND the results. Hope that clarifies my question more.

`DECLARE @Username NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Username = 'myname'
DECLARE @Groupname NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Groupname = 'Office Group'
select u.FullName, u.Username, u.UserID, u.Email, g.Groupname from users u
join GroupMembers gm
on gm.UserID = u.UserID
join Groups g
on g.GroupID = gm.GroupID
where u.username = @Username`

[image: SQL Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set up a parameter table in Excel and use that in a query to select data?
A few days ago I created a [3.5 minute video](https://youtu.be/nZaJeglih8I) for another question, illustrating step-by-step how to create a Power Query function that retrieves an Excel parameter value and use that in a query.
In the video this is used to filter data in a table "Executions" on parameters start and end date/time. 
Likewise, in your case that would be filtering data in your table on parameters Username and Groupname.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Manage Parameters feature.  You can define Parameters and reference them in your M code.  Once a Parameter is created, you'll see them appear as an option in many Power Query windows, e.g. the Filter Rows dialog.

https://blogs.office.com/2016/10/27/october-2016-updates-for-get-transform-in-excel-2016-and-the-power-query-add-in/

This feature was inherited from Power BI, so you can search on that to find more in-depth info.